# Netransitiva uzo de «indi»

Tags: word-usage

Mi ĵus kontrolis la difinon de *indi* en [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#indi) kaj surprizis min ke ĝi estas markita transitiva. La tuta difino estas nur unu vorto:

> **indi** (tr) Meriti.

Mi kutime aŭdas tiun vorton kiel *indi* + *infinitivo* sen alia substantivo. Tial ne estas tre klare ĉu la infinitivo rolas kiel subjekto aŭ objekto. Jen kelkaj ekzemploj kiujn mi trovis en [Tesktaro](http://tekstaro.com/):

> Ne indas ripeti ilin ĉi tie.

> Sed ne indas seke rakonti pri tiaĵoj.

> Tamen indas mencii la fakton ke la dioj faras malbonon kaj eĉ mortigas la anojn, kiuj kontraŭas la kutimojn.

Do, la demando estas: kiel tiu uzo rilatas al la difino de PIV? Mi ne povas imagi ke oni povus anstataŭigi *indi* per *meriti* en tiuj ekzemploj. Ĉu tia uzo estas erara, aŭ ĉu ĝi efektive estas alia difino de la vorto kiu ne aperas en PIV? Aŭ eble estas aŭ implicita subjekto aŭ objekto kiu donas sencon al la frazo?

Comment: Tiun tutan tempon mi sentis surprizon ke estis difino de la vorto en PMEG - kaj des pli ke la klarigo tie de Bertilo ne kontentigis vin. Mi vidas nun ke vi volis skribi "PIV".

Comment: In "Ne indas ripeti ilin ĉi tie" the infinitive "ripeti" is not the object, but the subject of "indas".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La verbo "indi" estas iom stranga, ĉar ĝi havas du sencojn: "esti inda" kaj "meriti". PIV ne mencias la sencon "esti inda", kvankam ĝi nuntempe estas tre ofta.

Answer (score 4):

Tre interesa demando. Dankon.

Por trovi tre interesan respondon mi kontrolis en tekstaro por "indi" uzata kiel verbon.

- Ĝi ne indis la penon!
- Mi tion ne indas.
- (Li) parolis kun ĉiuj, kiuj indis koniĝon

Pri la demandoj pri infitivoj, pensu pri "voli". Ankaŭ voli estas transitiva - sed funkcs kun verboj kaj frazeroj. La verboj kaj frazeroj estas la objekto de la verbo.

Comment: Do, kiu estas korekta: ”Ĝi ne indas aĉeti” aŭ ”Ĝin ne indas aĉeti”? (Anstataŭ ”Ĝi ne aĉetindas”.)

Comment: Mia sento estas ke "ili indas konigxon" farigxas "indas konigxi al ili. Do "konigxi" estas la objekto" la la subjekto farigxas nepersona. Simile "Gxi ne indas acxeton" farigxas "ne indas acxeti gxin."

Comment: Dankon pro la klarigo. :-) Mi nun miras – ĉu iuj el la revortigoj estus nekorektaj: ”ne indas aĉeti ĝin” > ”ne indas ĝin aĉeti” > ”ĝin ne indas aĉeti” >  ”aĉeti ĝin ne indas” > ”ĝin aĉeti ne indas”

Comment: En viaj 3 ekzemploj estas klare kio estas subjekto kaj kio estas objekto kaj ne estas malfacile vidi kiel tiuj rilatas al la difino en PIV. Tamen mia demando estis pri la specifa okazo kiam estas nur infinitivo. Mi komprenas ke infinitivo povas roli kiel subjekto aŭ objekto, sed en miaj ekzemploj ne estas klare kiu la verbo estas, kaj ankaŭ ne klaras kio estas la implicita mankanta subjekto aŭ objekto. Bedaŭrinde mi ne kredas ke via respondo respondas al la demando.

Comment: Jes, mi vidas tion. Tial mi afisxis duan demandon. Mi tamen kredas ke tiu cxi respondo respondas al la gxenerala dubo pri la difino de "indas" kiel "meritas (tr)".

Answer (score 2):

Alternativa klarigo estas ke en la ekzemploj:

> Ne indas ripeti ilin ĉi tie.
>
> Sed ne indas seke rakonti pri tiaĵoj.
>
> Tamen indas mencii la fakton ke la dioj faras malbonon kaj eĉ mortigas la anojn, kiuj kontraŭas la kutimojn.

En ĉiu okazo, "indas" vere signifas "estas inde."

Komparu:

> ne estas inde perdi tempon por la lernado de lingvo, en kiu neniu nin komprenos krom la aŭtoro

Se oni akceptas tiun klarigon, oni devus akcepti ke estas du malsamaj difinoj de "indi" aŭ eventuale ke la uzo de ”indas“ ja estas erara en tiu situacio.

Comment: Jes, tio estas efektive kion mi supozis kaj klarigis en la demando: ke mankas difino en PIV por ĉi tia alternativa uzo. Estus bone iel havi konfirmon ke tio estas ĝusta penso.

Comment: Mi ne komprenas. Mi jxus relegis vian demandon kaj mi vidas nenion en gxi pri "estas inde." Mi volis diri ke oni (cxu bone cxu malbone) ofte sxangxas "estas x-e" al simple "X-as". Cetere, kian konfirmon estus kontentiga por vi?